# Python Selenium (Chrome Webdriver) - Define URL based on values

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm looking for a way to loop through URL's based on a list of values in Python Selenium.
I have a list like: 
1000
1200
1250

A website is structured like: https://example.com/1000/events.
I'd be able to reach this by: driver.get(https://example.com/1000/events)
However, I'd ideally define the list above, and then trace the URL based on the list values. 
Ideally, make the script go from https://example.com/1000/events, and after that script is done, go to https://example.com/1200/events etc.

Anyone that is able to help me with this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Define a base_url like this :

```
base_url = 'https://example.com/{}/events'
```

Then if your list is for example :

```
my_list = [1000, 1200, 1500]
```

You can do :

```
for num in my_list:
    url = base_url.format(num)
    <do your stuff here using url variable>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems to work, I'm just wondering, how do I make it go from the first of the list to the second of the list? For now it seems to grab 1 value out of my_list

Comment: what do you mean ? `for num in my_list` iterates over all elements of your list. Be sure however to not use the same name for `url` and `base_url` variables.

Comment: I think I'm not sure what you meant with:' <do your stuff here using url variable>' Do I put the list values there again?

Comment: for example, you could do `driver.get(url)`